# '08 Impala Front power locks don't work properly in hot weather

Tags: locks, impala

I have a 2008 Chevrolet Impala LS with approximately 80,000 miles.

I've noticed that *both* front door power locks are not working properly when it's very warm out, especially if we're parked in the sun.

My wife first noticed it because the remote fob wasn't working for the driver's door. I did further testing and confirmed that using the switches on the inside of either door also present the problem.

Once every 3-5 minutes, I can use the switches to either lock *or* unlock the front doors. After that, they stop working until I wait again, as if they've lost their charge. At first, when they're not working, I can see the locks shake as the motor moves but they don't go up or down. Continued attempts are silent: you can't hear or see the motor trying to work. After the few minute wait, the front locks work fine, once, as if there is no problem at all.

My suspicions about this being heat-induced have been confirmed, because this problem now occurs every day the outside temperature is above about 80° F, and less if in direct sunlight. There has also been at least one time when it spread to affect one of the rear locks when it was especially hot. **Knowing heat exacerbates the issue doesn't, however, help me source the issue.**

I don't *think* this is a motor issue, as the motor works fine when it seems to have power. Outside of that, I don't know how to troubleshoot where the problem is occurring. I have read that there are wiring issues common with GMs around this year model.

**How do I troubleshoot and/or diagnose this issue?**

More details on what *is* working:

- All other power features work fine.
- Door, lock and power fuses are fine.
- Rear doors are 100% unaffected and fine.
- Manually moving the locks works to  correctly lock/unlock the door.
- Using the key in the driver's side door works to unlock the driver's door.
- Ignition on/off doesn't affect the issue.
- I swapped out the power lock relay in the console fuse box with another working one, with no effect. Relay seems to be working fine.

When you hit the indoor switches once, with a door open, they do not lock immediately. This is a feature of the car, and normally works fine. However, with my problem, if there isn't a "charge" the locks won't lock after the normal 30 seconds or so, but they *will* lock after the 3-5 minutes, as if the lock order had been queued until power was back to the switches. When it finally activates, all locks successfully lock.

Additionally, if the key is not in the ignition and one door is open, when you press the lock button sometimes the console will chime, and  nothing else happens. This is not the typically warning chime from locking your doors, but more like the console alert chimes such as "wiper fluid low".

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the Body Control Module (BCM). It could be due to a faulty ground or some other reason. One thing you can try is to disconnect the batter and let the vehicle sit for ~30 minutes. This might reset everything and get it back to functioning. If not, it's going to be *very hard* to diagnose.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for the tip. I'll try disconnecting the battery tonight when I get back home. If it *is* the BCM, is there anything else I can try, in addition to the disconnect, to test to confirm it's the problem? However, if there's an issue with wiring, contacts or other electrical, this won't help, will it?

Comment: Disconnecting the battery will not help with wiring, contacts or other electrical issues. I'm doubting it will help in your situation, either, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Paulster2 I didn't get to the battery, b/c of the other things I tried last night and then needing the car. But, as of today (which has been cooler), the problem seems to have gone away, so I can't really troubleshoot any further.

Comment: You *just* have to love intermittent issues. Hardest thing in the world to diagnose.

Comment: I agree with Paulster2, sounds like an issue with the BCM. I had the same thing happen on my 2001 Impala LS. Ordered a new BCM, replaced it myself (15 minute job) and it resolved the issue. The BCM is underneath the instrument panel -- watch not to hurt your back installing it.

Comment: @ChrisHiszpanski My BCM needs to be programmed by a dealer and they won't allow a self install and I've been quoted $600-900. It's pretty ridiculous.

Comment: Wow, they either have no idea what they're talking about or trying to rip you off. Yes, the BCM module does need to be programmed by the dealer. I can't remember how much it was exactly, but it wasn't more than $100. Got it done at Boardwalk Chevrolet in Redwood City, CA.

Comment: @ChrisHiszpanski Yup, dealers here suck. Have to pay for diagnosis, labor, reprogramming and can't provide my own part. Gotta wait until I move and get quotes elsewhere.

Comment: Ouch, yeah that sucks. One option I was considering was to try reading out the flash memory on the old BCM module and writing it onto the new one. But that route takes a good amount of reverse engineering, reading datasheets, building custom programmers, and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced all 4 door lock actuators on my f350 for being weak. They sounded like they were trying and they did make the locks move but not go up or down fully. I'd say the 2 your having problems with are weak and the heat just makes it worse. Pull your door panel off and follow the mechanism for the locks till you find the actuator. Mine were $35 for all 4 and it'll take a couple hours generally.

Answer (score 0):

If it gets better with the engine running suspect the battery of not having high enough voltage but still putting out the current for the starter (possible bad cell).

Heat could be breaking a specific circuit that is responsible for mainly powering the actuators, check the voltage and amperage at the actuator when it is working properly and when it is not. Capacitors store the energy but quickly discharge if there is not much current to recharge them which gives you that winding down feeling.